# Clickable Popup Entries Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, background, popup

I'm a beginner when it comes to these things and I can't figure out the documentation, but...

What I want done is that you click the page_action icon, it pops up a small window of options, and then when the user clicks one of those options, it executes a script (QCScript.js) on the given page (not in the popup).

So far here's what I've got:

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "友達",
    "version": "1.00",
    "default_locale": "en",
    "description": "A helper program",
    "icons": {...},
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "images/icon19.png",
            "38": "images/icon38.png"
        },
        "default_title": "友達".
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "author": "ME",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://omfglibrariesarethebest.edu/*"
    ]
}
```

eventpage.js

```
document.getElementById("option1").onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "QCScript.js"});
});
```

popup.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <p><a href="#" id="option1">Oh boy option 1</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

QCScript.js

```
Unimportant because it works when pasted into the console.
```

So, to summarise, I'd like it to make a popup with a list of items. Then, in this case, when you click "Oh boy option 1," it runs the Javascript in QCScript.js. When they click option two, it can run a different script.

I'm just... I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Your current *eventpage.js* should be better called *popup.js* and directly included in your popup:

```
<html>
<head><script src="popup.js"></script></head>
<body>
    <p><a href="#" id="option1">Oh boy option 1</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And make sure your code runs only once the DOM is ready:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("option1").onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "QCScript.js"});
    });
});
```

And you need a new *eventpage.js* to show the page action icon on the proper pages. Something like:

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf('example.com') > -1) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
};
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

Comment: Thanks! That certainly removed the errors. However, I now need to show the icon on the pages in question (so they can click it). Wouldn't I need an event page for that? How would that go?

Comment: @Lani yes, you will need one. I didn't notice you were using page action. I've edited my answer.